# Redirect according to the first directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following URL structure

```
Index
-Parent1
--SubParent1
--SubParent2
---Child <-
-Parent2
-...
```

and I want to get something like this

```
Index
-Allparent
--Child <-
```

so far I have something like this

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ /allparents/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I can't find a way to apply my rule only to children with Parent1 page,I tried something like that, but I can't get it to work

```
RewriteRule ^/Parent1/([^/]+)/?$ /allparents/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: The documentation of the rewriting module clearly states, that the rule patterns are used to match _relative_ paths in requests for rules implemented in distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). So remove the leading slash ( / ) from the matching pattern or make it optional (`^/?...`).

Comment: sorry i'm new to this and it's my first time with rewriting, should i try this?

`RewriteRule ^Parent1/([^/]+)/?$ allparents/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: Is `/Index/` the document root? And the `.htaccess` file is located at `/Index/.htaccess` (in the document root? Is that a "URL structure" or "file structure" at the top? That rule would seem to target `SubParents`, not the `Child` as indicated in your "URL structure"? Although `SubParent1` is a "child" of `Parent1` in your description.